# return false not works for ajax success function in yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I want to set validation of unique email id in yii but it not works properly, so where is the problem.
my form code is as below:

```
  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model1,'user_email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model1, 'user_email', array('maxlength' => 300)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model1, 'user_email', array('clientValidation' => 'js:customValidateemail(messages,this.id)'), false, true);
          $infoFieldFile1 = (end($form->attributes)); ?> 
    <p class="emailUniqueCheck" style="margin-left: 24%; color: red;">    
  </div>
```

my ajax code is as below:

```
<script>
function customValidateemail(messages,id){
    var nameC= '#'+id;  
    var a = $(nameC).val();
    if (a == '') {
        messages.push('Email Id is empty.');
        return false;
    }
    var email = $("#Registration_user_email").val();
    $(".emailUniqueCheck").html('<img alt="Loader" src="/images/loading.gif" />');
    $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>"+"/Supplier/checkUniqueEmail?email="+a,
            data:'req=add_more',
            dataType:'html',
            type:'POST',
            async: false,
            success:function(resp){
                if(resp == 1) {
                $(".emailUniqueCheck").html("Email Already exists.");
                return false;
                } else {
                $(".emailUniqueCheck").html("Proceed.");    
                } 
            },
            error:function(er){
                alert("An error has occured, Please reload/refresh the page and try again.");
            }
        });
}
```

here, vaidation works for empty email means `if(a == '') { alert('bla bla'); }` and and page also not submits on click of submit button.(as required.)

For ajax response validation works properly but only `return false;` not works. and form submits. i tried many things but not works. so can any one help me?

Comment: Try to make synchronous ajax request instead of async .. 
This will block your browser waiting the response but your return FALSE will have some effect.

Comment: what you try to say??? please explain briefly.

Comment: use $.ajax instead of $.post. You can make async:false using $.ajax . Do let me know if you want me to modify your code to work properly.

Comment: see my edited code.... but still not works . where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Since the call is not an asynchronous , you need to return false after ajax call

var isValid = false;
function customValidateemail(messages, id) {
var nameC = '#' + id;
var a = $(nameC).val();
if (a == '') {
    messages.push('Email Id is empty.');
    return false;
}
var email = $("#Registration_user_email").val();
$(".emailUniqueCheck").html('<img alt="Loader" src="/images/loading.gif" />');
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>" + "/Supplier/checkUniqueEmail?email=" + a,
    data: 'req=add_more',
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: funsuccess(),
    error: funerr()
});
return isValid;
 }
function funsuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
if (data == 1) {
    $(".emailUniqueCheck").html("Email Already exists.");
    return true;
} else {
    $(".emailUniqueCheck").html("Proceed.");
}
isValid = true;
}
 function funerr(err) {  
 alert("An error has occured, Please reload/refresh the page and try  again;
isValid = true;
}
```

Comment: it goes in funerr() function because "resp" is undefined for all case..... what to do now?

Comment: I have edited the answer. 'data' is inbuilt parameter. See this line,  function,funsuccess(data){}

Comment: can't see any edition in code... pls explain. and should not isValid variable inside the function?

Comment: What is the problem coming?

Comment: still going in error function.. and i alert data then it returns undefined.

Comment: Add you success and error handler outside function customValidateemail(). If still error comes please check whether your other ajax call parameter(url, data...) are correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84425/discussion-between-vivek-ranjan-and-dharmesh-patel).